# Javascript - Regex match issue

Tags: javascript

I have created this Regex function and it returns `false` because of the second condition, but I cannot undestand why?

```js
function telephoneCheck(str) {
  if (str.match(/[!?]/) !== null) {
    return false;
  } else if (str.match(/\d/g).length === 11 && str[0] !== 1) {
    return false;
  }
};

console.log(telephoneCheck("1 555-555-5555"));
```

Comment: Please read this page in its entirety, to make sure people can best help answer your questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is a syntax here because of extra `(` after function. `function(telephoneCheck(str)` Please make sure to post compilable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str[0]` will be the **string** `"1"`, and you're checking if it equals the **number** `1`. Using `===` or `!==` compares the types of the variables as well as the values.

You want `str[0] !== "1"`

Comment: also you can use `!=` or `==`. that type isn't a factor in comparison